# How do you pack a gem into your rails engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm building a rails engine and I need to pack a gem inside it because it is not available publicly.  What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to vendor the gem, at a point when you do have access to the gem that is not publicly available. This will make the source code, but not the location of, the not publicly available gem available. Here is [a guide describing how to vendor a single rails gem, with or without bundler](https://makandracards.com/makandra/538-freeze-vendor-unpack-a-single-ruby-gem-with-and-without-bundler).

Comment: Will this work?  My understanding is that when you create a rails engine and you add that engine to a normal rails app.. if you run bundle install.. it will not run the gemfile of the engine.. it only runs the gemspec.. this link you gave seems to require modifying the gemfile but that doesn't seem like it will work?  The gemspec does not support vendoring gems by itself.

Comment: Yes, I believe it will work. This may be somewhat of an oversimplification, but when you are developing engines, you can use either the gemfile or the gemspec. The main difference is that the gemspec gems become dependencies of the implementing application, while the gemfile gems do not. This will allow you to manipulate the gem to get it vendored. The code in the vendor directory will still be available to the implementing app (but you may need to explicitly require it in your engine). Give it a shot, it's fairly easy to try...

Answer (score 0):

In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'super-private-sneaky-gem', :git => 'https://github.com/Inc1982/super-private-sneaky-gem', :branch => 'master'
```

Comment: When I then create an app and bundle in the rails engine, it does not call the gemfile inside the rails engine to load it this way.  Have you gotten this to work?